# Trying to figure out some Javascript to extract a field from a JSON response to a raw webhook trigger in Zapier

Tags: json, field, zapier

I have a raw JSON response from a Zapier Webhook trigger. I am looking for a way to make it easy to get to each of the nested fields in CUSTOMFIELDS AND LINKS for successive Zap steps. The JSON body looks like this:

```
{"entity":{
  "OPPORTUNITY_ID":22992638,
  "OPPORTUNITY_NAME":"Test 5",
  "PROBABILITY":10,
  "BID_CURRENCY":"USD",
  "BID_TYPE":"Fixed Bid",
  "CATEGORY_ID":6132227,
  "PIPELINE_ID":575195,
  "STAGE_ID":2172640,
  "OPPORTUNITY_STATE":"OPEN",
  "RESPONSIBLE_USER_ID":1689885,
  "OWNER_USER_ID":1689885,
  "DATE_CREATED_UTC":"2019-01-15T21:11:50.28",
  "DATE_UPDATED_UTC":"2019-01-15T21:12:10.92",
  "VISIBLE_TO":"EVERYONE",
  "CUSTOMFIELDS":[{
    "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID":"Tax_Matters_Contact__c",
    "FIELD_VALUE":275224094
  }],
  "TAGS":[],
  "LINKS":[{
    "LINK_ID":199045197,
    "CONTACT_ID":275224094,
    "OPPORTUNITY_ID":22992638
  },
  {
    "LINK_ID":199045198,
    "OPPORTUNITY_ID":22992638,
    "ORGANISATION_ID":130032601
  }
  ]
}}
```

Thanks to David from Zapier, I run this Javascript in a Code step and it works great for CONTACT_ID as this is usually in the first order of the array but it only finds the ORGANIZATION_ID if there is no CONTACT_ID aka it skips over the first record and finds the second. I'm guessing it gets the first listed in the array and then doesn't continue, but I don't know why it won't iterate to the next one as it's merely a raw webhook. Any idea how to get this to work?

The array provides the record for CONTACT_ID first and ORGANISATION_ID next if it exists, but this order can change/reverse or another one can also appear such as PROJECT_ID. I'd like to find them all or any with one code step so the output provides for the successive stages of the Zap.

```
const j = JSON.parse(inputData.body)
return j.entity.LINKS.find(l => l.CONTACT_ID || l.ORGANISATION_ID) || {}
```

Here's my Zap:

[Here's my code step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdg7q.jpg)

[Here's the results when CONTACT_ID is found in my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nu3mE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

You mentioned in a comment that you wanted to find the first item in LINKS that had either a `contact_id` or a `organisation_id`. This parses the json and returns the object (if any) that matches that

```js
const j = JSON.parse(inputData.entity)
return j.entity.LINKS.find(l => l.CONTACT_ID || l.ORGANISATION_ID) || {}
```

This will return `{"LINK_ID":199045197, "CONTACT_ID":275224094, "OPPORTUNITY_ID":22992638}` for the object above, or blank if none of the items in link have either of those keys.

You'll note that my structure matches your code from your original question. Upon looking more closely, I realized it should have worked in the first place. so, there's a chance that this won't work because of something in your setup. I'd update your question with screenshots of the setup screen so we can more closely tell why your code didn't work in the first place.

Comment: Thanks David. What I'm really trying to do is extract the CONTACT_ID or ORGANISATION_ID and only the first one if more than one exist. I figured out how to use Python regular expressions to do it, but would love to know how to use Javascript and dot notation to get into the custom fields.

Comment: I cannot use [0...9] as I don't always know what order the nested field is in. Zapier, as you well know, parses nested fields but doesn't really have a great way of getting to the nested fields in the next step. Splitting is often recommended, but that's a tedious process and the Python method seems to work well, but it sure would be awesome to just put return j.entity.links.CONTACT_ID and get that value. When I do this it loops through the array and runs the zap more than once creating the last stage more than once e.g. create a Pandadoc or Task.

Comment: I'm so close, but still working on the perfect solution.

Thanks again David!

Eric Greenspan
Chief Clever Officer
74Systems.com
Zapier Certified Expert | Insightly Hero | Certified QuickBooks ProAdvisor | Xero Partner

Comment: To be clear, what you really want is the first element in `LINKS` that has a `CONTACT_ID` or a `ORGANISATION_ID`? If so, I can update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I updated my post with the images David. I get only the first record with this method. It seems to stop processing, at least in the sample output. But without the right output, I can't map the next steps.

Comment: I think I get it now. The return statement is going to stop when it finds one of the items first. Is there a way to tell it to simply get any of the ones that match/exist, meaning one, the other, or both?

Comment: change `find` to `filter`

Comment: didn't work David. I currently have two steps: one for contact and one for org. Would be nice to have only one, but I can live with this. Surely seems this is something the miraculous Zapier should handle better. It's designed to eliminate the need for coding and while I love the code feature, extracting data should be #1 priority no? I'm sure there's a good reason for the limitation but if cracked, the sky's the limit. I've been bugging insightly about updating their Zaps. Based on an old API sadly and limited update capability. I had someone build an app. Might start focusing there soon.

Comment: Yep, it's definitely an area of improvement. We have to cover such a wide array of use cases that unfortunately, some get handled better than others. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: So any idea why return j.entity.LINKS.filter(l => l.CONTACT_ID || l.ORGANISATION_ID || l.PROJECT_ID) || {} won't work? I get only . 
runtime_meta
duration_ms
2
memory_used_mb
23
logs
async
false
PROJECT_ID
8761797
id
c2Da5S1nGtfOJ0tsIxNNWidicRX57ae5
CONTACT_ID
281018031
LINK_ID
199537619 but it just ignores the ORGANISATION_ID or at least the test code doesn't show it. It might be looping but that's exactly what I want to avoid so I can avoid multiple actions in subsequent steps from occurring.

Comment: that seems like it should work - that's finding the first item in that list that has any of those properties and returning it. the output of that code step will always be 1 object either the found one or the blank one. sounds like you're hitting the blank one. the good news is that it's just regular js, so you can test your code in the chrome console until it does exactly what you expect